# Azure Blob returning 403 on upload

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function that generates a sas key that I later use to upload files to my blob. Here is how I generate the sas key :

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("sasimagecontainer");
container.CreateIfNotExists();

static string GetContainerSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
    //Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
    //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(25);
    sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Add | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create;

    //Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
    string sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

    //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
    return container.Uri + sasContainerToken + "&comp=list&restype=container";
}
```

And then I can call

> GetContainerSasUri(container));

to get the sas key. But when I use the following code to call it :

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(thesaskey);
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
{
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

I keep getting 403 errors. That's all I'm getting from debugging in VS 2017, I'm not sure how can I acquire more information about this problem.

I already looked into most similar threads on SO regarding similar issues and applied possible fixes, like for example the "&comp=list&restype=container" parameter at the end.

// I tried adding SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List to permissions, that didn't work.

// I added literally all the permissions (except None, of course) to check if that might change something - it doesn't. The goal is still to only have  permissions to upload.

Comment: You might need to include the `x-ms-blob-type` header on the client. I think the query parameter (comp) only worked for blocklist uploads. I'm not sure if this works the same for a container-level URL.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm not quite sure how to add the header. I might be wrong but I think UploadFromStreamAsync handles the request itself and I don't have access to modify its header.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) You have to add it to the request the client makes. As I said, I only know this to be true for actual blobs. I'm not sure about the container.

Comment: Did you checked the returned SAS? Is it valid? Also can you try to add `SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List` and see whether that changes anything

Comment: I don't think I know of any other way of checking the sas key than making an upload request like I presented. If there is something else I could use, please let me know.

Comment: I mean does the returned string looks like a SAS?

Comment: I think it does. It has sv, sig, st, se, and sp parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error and this is how I fixed it:

You need to pass the SAS to a `CloudBlobContainer` instead of a `CloudBlockBlob`. Then use the container to retrieve a blob reference (you may want to use the filename property of your file):

```
var container = new CloudBlobContainer(thesaskey);
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("<yourFileName>");
await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(@"YOURPATH")
```

Notice that there is a convenience method `UploadFromFileAsync` that you can use

---

Here is the console application that I used to test it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
            "<AccountName>",
            "<AccountKey>");
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();


        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("sasimagecontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var sasUri = GetContainerSasUri(container);


        var container2 = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sasUri));
        var blob2 = container2.GetBlockBlobReference("blobCreatedViaSAS.txt");
        blob2.UploadFromFileAsync(@"D:\test.txt").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    private static string GetContainerSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container)
    {

        //Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
        //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
        sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
        sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write |
                                     SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create |
                                     SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Add | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

        //Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
        var sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

        //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
        return container.Uri + sasContainerToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. if you upload a file into a container it becomes a blob.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed something up. I deleted the comment.